# iOS OTP Auto suggestion is not working in Arabic

Tags: ios, ios12, swift5, one-time-password

I have OTP Auto suggestion in my app. its is not working in Arabic language, the same is working fine in the english and french. so can someone help me on this?

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. Have you solved that someway?

Answer (score 2):

Sms have to contain *"code"* or *"passcode"* word on any language rights before code.

Answer (score 1):

The digits should be in English like:

- رمز التحقق: 1234
- رمز التفعيل: 1234

You can try different combinations in Messages app to see which one works, the one that works with auto fill will be underlined.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old , but this issue still happen for none english OTP message , so here is the final solution for none english message formatting :

[image]

When you see the underline on the OTP digits that is mean the device AI is reading it as OTP and you've success translated your OTP message .